# Where will I find S3TC compressed texture for opengl?

Tags: linux, opengl-es-2.0

I am a newbie in linux and opengl. I am trying to find s3tc compressed textures on internet but not able to find it anywhere. Can anyone suggest how to find one such s3tc compressed texture online. Also for opengl what is the file extension for s3tc compressed textures. I could only find dds file formats for the same(but I guess that are for Windows platform so not for linux i guess), I do not know what to do with them to get compressed s3tc textures for opengl from them?Sorry but please help me out as I am totally new in this area.

Comment: S3TC are indeed DXT texures that's why they are stored in DDS format. This format has quite simple header format and I've successfully loaded DXT textures in Android on Tegra2/3 GPUs. Image quality is on par with ETC1.

Comment: Thanks keaukraine. I too initially guessed it might be the same thing, but was not pretty sure. Thanks, Actually we want to provide support for a particular texture compression format in webgl-webkit, and the best starting place for guiding us was to see how S3TC is supported in webgl-Webkit for our DTV platform. So, while searching online about it when I saw this API : gl.compressedTexImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, data); I began to wonder from where I would get some S3TC compressed data to be passed in the last parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDS may be a Windows Format (Direct Draw Surface).  But as it just contains data, you may well use it on Linux, also.

Regarding S3TC you might find some answers in this (pretty old) tutorial by NVidia: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/opengl-texture-compressions3tc-tutorial

If you can't find any textures online, you might need to create them yourself.

On the other hand the guys from cruden/racer.nl have posted a dds texture loader on their site: http://www.racer.nl/tech/dds.htm - I guess this is the best help you can get, as you question does not state the purpose why you need s3tc textures ...

Comment: Thanks Stoff. I too initially guessed it might be the same thing, but was not pretty sure. Thanks, Actually we want to provide support for a particular texture compression format in webgl-webkit, and the best starting place for guiding us was to see how S3TC is supported in webgl-Webkit for our DTV platform. So, while searching online about it when I saw this API : gl.compressedTexImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, data); I began to wonder from where I would get some S3TC compressed data to be passed in the last parameter.